# Order of execution when using synchronous $.ajax call

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am trying to understand how synchronous ajax calls fit in with the order of execution, because I am getting some strange bugs.

```
// (1)
$.ajax({
  async: false,
  url: url0,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) { 
       // (2)
  });
// (3)
```

Is it true that with synchronous ajax calls, the order of evaluation will be `(1)`, followed by `(2)`, and then *always* followed by `(3)`? I want to particularly verify that `(3)` is only executed after the entire body of `(2)`.

Comment: Synchronous AJAX can easily lead to browser lockups and has been deprecated since jQuery 1.8. It might make sense to try an async approach.

Comment: @Jon How would you solve the problems when I claim I "need" a synchronous approach? i.e. Loading and parsing all the authentication data from the server until I let the user in to a protected area?

Comment: By refactoring the code of course. There are many options and I wouldn't dream to provide an one-size-fits-all solution, but one pattern you might consider is to make `{3}` a function and write `$.ajax(...).done({3})` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it's not the right way to go about this. Instead, move the code in (3) into the success handler (2).

> Can you explain a little more why it matters if they achieve the same effect? What if (2) has nothing to do with the data gotten from the ajax call?

A synchronous call will block the browsers runtime until it completes. This means that the UI is completely unresponsive for the user.

If you want to logically separate your current (2) from (3), you can bind multiple success handlers like this:

```
var d = $.ajax({
  url: url0,
  dataType: 'json'
});
d.success(function() {
  // (2)
});
d.success(function() {
  // (3)
});
```

They will be executed in sequence.

Comment: Can you explain a little more why it matters if they achieve the same effect? What if (2) has nothing to do with the data gotten from the ajax call?